# Show that there are exactly two values in $\{0, 1, ..., N - 1\}$ satisfying $x^{2} \equiv a \pmod{N}$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

> Fix a positive integer $N > 1$. We say that $a$ is a quadratic residue modulo $N$ if there exists $x$ such that $a \equiv x^{2} \pmod{N}$.
>
> Let $N$ be an odd prime and $a$ be a non-zero quadratic residue modulo $N$. Show that there are exactly two values in $\{0, 1, ..., N - 1\}$ satisfying $x^{2} \equiv a \pmod{N}$.

This means to prove that there are exactly two values of $x$ that satisfy $x^{2} \equiv a \pmod{N}$.

I think I should prove that there are at most two values and at least two values that satisfy the above constraints.

I know that because $a$ is a quadratic residue modulo $N$, $a \equiv x^{2} \pmod{N}$, and given in the problem is $x^{2} = a \pmod{N}$.

I can combine these two equations using modular arithmetic to either $x^{2}a = x^{2}a \pmod{N}$ or $x^{2} + a = x^{2} + a \pmod{N}$.

I don't know if this is on the right track or how to continue the proof.

This is a homework question, so I'd be a grateful for a hint of some sort that nudges me in the right direction.

Comment: Writing $a=x^2$ is the same as writing $x^2=a$, all you are doing is writing down tautologies. Hints: $\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z}$ is a field.

Comment: Hint: Suppose a is a non-zero perfect square in Z. What are the two roots?

Comment: $N$ divides $x^{2} - a$ (because $x^{2} = a \pmod{N}$), so I can find the two roots of $x$, which are $x + a$ and $x - a$, but I'm not sure how to find the two roots of $a$.

Comment: Oh, I think I know how to find it now. $N$ divides $a - x^2$ (because $a = x^2 \pmod{N}$), so the two roots of $a$ are $a + x$ and $a -x$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Detailed outline:** We will use the fact that any integer is congruent to precisely one of $0,1,2, \dots, N-1$ modulo $N$.

Suppose that $b^2\equiv a \pmod{p}$. Then $(-b)^2\equiv a\pmod{p}$. If you show that $-b$ is not congruent to $b$ modulo $N$, you will have shown that there are at least two solutions.

Suppose that $b^2\equiv a\pmod{N}$ and $x^2\equiv a \pmod{N}$. Then $N$ divides $x^2-b^2$, that is, $N$ divides $(x-b)(x+b)$. Recall that if a prime divides a product, it divides at least one of the terms.

Comment: Thank you for the outline! If I show that $-b$ is not congruent to $b \pmod{N}$, I'm not sure how that shows there are at least two solutions?

Comment: We are told that $a$ is a quadratic residue, so $x^2\equiv a \pmod{N}$ has at least one solution. Let $b$ be a solution. Then $-b$ is also a solution. If you prefer to keep things within the interval $0$ to $N-1$, you can say instead that $N-b$ is a solution. So we have the solution $b$, and the solution $N-b$. If we can show they are *different*, then there are at least two solutions. By the way, here we will use the fact that $N\ne 2$. If $N=2$, the congruence $x^2\equiv 1\pmod{N}$ has a solution $1$. By our argument $2-1$ is also a solution, but  $1$ and $2-1$ are the same.

Comment: Just for my notes: "In modular arithmetic, congruence means having the same remainder when divided by a specified integer."

Comment: Yes, so in the second part, if $x^2\equiv a \pmod{N}$, and $b^2\equiv a\pmod{N}$, then $x^2$ and $b^2$ have the same remainder, so $x^2-b^2$ has remainder $0$. For congruence of $c$ and $d$, I would prefer to define $c\equiv d\pmod{N}$ by saying  it means $N$ divides $c-d$. That way, we can avoid for a while the concept of remainder, and its properties.

Comment: "Recall that if a prime divides a product, it divides at least one of the terms." But how does this show that there are no more than two solutions? Also, I'm not sure what $c$ and $d$ represent?

Comment: We got to $N$ divides $(x-b)(x+b)$. Thus $N$ divides $x-b$ or $N$ divides $x+b$. If $N$ divides $x-b$, then $x\equiv b\pmod{N}$. If $N$ divides $x+b$, then $x\equiv -b\pmod{N}$. We have proved that **if** we are given a solution $b$, the only other possible solution is $\equiv -b\pmod{N}$, so there can be at most one solution other than $b$.

Comment: I think I get it now! Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: You are welcome. It takes a while to develop intuition about congruences. Concrete familiarity with smallish $N$ helps.

Answer (score 2):

Few remarks just to remind you some theorems about congruences when the modulus is *prime*:

1- If $p$ is a prime number and $P(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $k$, then $P(x) \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$ has at most $k$ number of solutions.

2- when $p$ is a prime number, $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ is an integral domain. That means whenever $a.b \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$ then $a \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$   or   $b \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$. This can be equivalently said as $p \mid ab \implies p \mid a$ or $p \mid b$.

3- Every finite integral domain is a field (This is more related to abstract algebra than elementary number theory though).

4- Notice that if $n\neq 1>0$ then  $2 \equiv 0 \pmod{n}$ if and only $n=2$. As a corrolary, $-1 \equiv 1 \pmod{n}$ if and only if $n=2$.

The rest is now clear as  André Nicolas has said:

If $a$ is a quadratic residue, then by definition there is at least one $x$ such that $x^2 \equiv a \pmod{N}$. But also $(-x)^2 \equiv a \pmod{N}$. Therefore if $x$ and $-x$ are different then we have found at least two solutions, also because of remark 1 we know that we can have at most 2 solutions because $P(x)=x^2-a$ is of degreee 2 and that proves there are exactly 2 solutions.

To show that $x \not\equiv -x \pmod{N}$ assume the opposite. If $x \equiv -x \pmod{N}$ then $2x \equiv 0 \pmod{N}$, but $2 \not\equiv 0 \pmod{N}$ because $N \neq 2$. That implies $x \equiv 0 \pmod{N}$.But that forces $a$ to be $0$ modulo $N$ which is contradiction.